# Set checkbox label as bold when checked in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a form-generator package and unfortunately it doesn't allow me to wrap the words "HDR Photography" in any tags. I'm too heavily invested in this package to abandon it.

I need to have this label bolded when the input box is checked though using jQuery or CSS.

The HTML shown below CANNOT be changed due to the form-generator package other than adding classes to the `input` tag.

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="track-order-change label-to-bold-if-checked" name="servicesSelected.hdrPhotos.selected">
      HDR Photography
    </label>
  </div>
```

On a sidenote, why does Bootstrap 3 have the `<input>` tag nested INSIDE the `<label>` tag? It's not a label! It doesn't make any semantic sense.

Comment: Can't jQuery be used to wrap the relevant text in an element?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to figure out how to do this at the moment actually...

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question - as it was asked - but it's easy enough to do: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u2ta91n4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it with jQuery:

```
$(".label-to-bold-if-checked").click( function(){
    var _parent = $(this).parent('label');
    $(this).is(':checked') ? _parent.addClass('selected') : _parent.removeClass('selected');
});


function updateLabels (targetedClass) {
    $(arguments[0]).each(function(){
        var _parent = $(this).parent('label');
        $(this).is(':checked') ? _parent.addClass('selected') : '';
    });
}
updateLabels('.label-to-bold-if-checked');
```

CSS:

```
label.selected{ font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: You're welcome! You could also get the text content by using `contents` and `filter` methods, and then check the nodeType(should be 3 for text node) and wrap your text content in an element, but that's tricky because you can have whitespaces before the input, an dyou would get more elements than you expected.

Comment: Bah, I should have thought a little bit more about this question. This solution works - it definitely bolds the label text when clicked, but it doesn't bold the labels that have been checked by default (ie. on page load) since it only fires on the click event.

Comment: You could also make some refactoring, by placing the parent variable and checking into a function, then call the function onclick and ondomready.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8786/)**

```
.label-to-bold-if-checked:checked + .label-check {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="checkbox">

     <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="track-order-change label-to-bold-if-checked" name="servicesSelected.hdrPhotos.selected"/>
     <label class="label-check">  HDR Photography
    </label>
  </div>
```

**Update**: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8788/)**

If you cant change the order, you can use span instead like this:

```
.label-to-bold-if-checked:checked + span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <label class="label-check">  
     <input type="checkbox" value="true" 
      class="track-order-change label-to-bold-if-checked" 
      name="servicesSelected.hdrPhotos.selected"/>
            <span>  HDR Photography</span>
    </label>
```

Comment: I do not have access to changing the order of the `input` and `label` tags. due to the form generator package that I've been using. Plus, Bootstrap 3 always nests `input` tags for checkboxes INSIDE of the `<label>` tags.